# Android: about monitor actions happened on UI layers as well as API call in log

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence

The primary purpose is to monitor how user can execute a plan in Android devices, like how to connect to wifi. I want to know the exact workflow of the user, like open what activity, UI click and the corresponding calls in the background. With those procedure, it is possible to verify whether one plan is feasible or not.

In the simulator or real devices, adb can connect and the relevant logging can be captures. But those logging are a little bit low-level and there are still gaps to link logging with UI operation. Furthermore, in order to reproduce users' behavior on Android, it also needs to know what parameters have been passed in the process.

The AndroidEnv, https://www.deepmind.com/publications/androidenv-the-android-learning-environment provides some possibilities, but still very limited.  Any idea or suggestion about this?

Comment: Not sure if this question is appropriate for StackOverflow. If the device is connected to a PC you can record user interaction of [touches](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#input) while using [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to record all interaction. If you are  trying to figure out a marketing/UX funnel, the app need to be instrumented to record all required user action similar to a web site/page, to be processed later.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for your reply. Actually I tries to capture UI click together with activity logging together with backend API call. All of those procedureces can be recorded and mapped to executable steps described in a plan. With those, I can verify if those steps are right or not. For all apps in android system. Something like, UI+logging of API call, then with those logs, I can reproduce via a programming agent.

Comment: Android Developer site has a section on testing: https://developer.android.com/training/testing You can search for third-party Android UI test frameworks. If you are asking how can I test UI interaction of system apps, realize that ODMs can move setting screens to different locations so all you will be able to do is replay actions for a particular model/OS version. If you really want to instrument all system apps, use a Custom ROM where you have such instrumentation.